# Differentiation inside recursive expression is not compatible with Manipulate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, manipulate, warning-messages

Define a sequence of function recursively:

```
f[n_, x_] := D[Exp[x] f[n - 1, x], x]
f[0, x_] = 1
```

Then, the following `Manipulate` command does not work:

```
Manipulate[Plot[f[n, x], {x, 0, 10}], {n, 1, 10, 1}]
```

It says that

> General::ivar: 0.0002042857142857143` is not a valid variable.

I also found out that the problem is due to the differentiation in `f[n_,x_]`. If I don't have differentiation operation, then everything works fine. Also, I found out that the definition `f` itself is not a problem, since `f[2,x]` gives the correct answer $2e^{2x}$.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Try `Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate@f[n, x], {x, 0, 10}], {n, 1, 10, 1}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Now it works, and I understand why Evaluate is needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition cannot evaluate for numeric arguments. Note

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[n_, x_] := D[Exp[x] f[n - 1, x], x]
f[0, x_] = 1;

f[1, 2]
```

[image]

Delay the variable being given a value until after the differentiation

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[n_Integer?Positive, x_] :=
  Module[{t}, D[Exp[t] f[n - 1, t], t] /. t -> x];
f[0, x_] = 1;

f[1, 2]

(* E^2 *)

Manipulate[
 LogPlot[f[n, x], {x, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {x, f[n, x]}],
 {{n, 1}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]